# How to fix" ERROR-invalid argument/option - 'Live' " in this code?

Tags: batch-file

So I want to close my live wallpaper when epic games launcher starts and then start it when i close the launcher and with other programs it worked fine but now it gives me this error message:ERROR: Invalid argument/option - 'Live'.

I think this is because the live wallpaper has spaces in its name, but I tried quotation marks and it still  doesn't work. Do you know what I should do?

```
@echo off
:TEST
tasklist /nh /fi "imagename eq EpicGamesLauncher.exe" | find /i "EpicGamesLauncher.exe" >nul 
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="1" goto TIMER
taskkill /im "DesktopHut Live v5.0.0.exe" /t /f
:TIMER
timeout /T 10
goto TEST2

:TEST2
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq EpicGamesLauncher.exe" 2>NUL | find /I /N "EpicGamesLauncher.exe">NUL 
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" goto TEST
tasklist /nh /fi "imagename eq  "DesktopHut Live v5.0.0.exe" "| find /i /n "DesktopHut Live v5.0.0.exe" >nul 
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" goto TEST
start " " "C:\Users\David\Desktop\DesktopHut Live v5.0.0.exe"
goto TEST

pause>nul
```

Comment: When you remove `@echo off` from the script and run it from the command line instead of double clicking it, which line throws that error?

Comment: If I am running it trough cmd it just closes the wallpaper and if the wallpaper is not running then it says error:process not found, but it doesn't even run the whole program it stops after the timer goes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the error message is that you've used a wrong syntax for the filter expression of `tasklist`:
 `tasklist /nh /fi "imagename eq  "DesktopHut Live v5.0.0.exe" "`

The filter expressions can have spaces in them and `tasklist` does not have any problems with them, The real problem is the limitation in the output of `tasklist` which is apparently fixed at 25 characters for the **Image Name** column, when using the default output formatting.

So assuming the process `DesktopHut Live v5.0.0.exe` is already running, The output of 
`tasklist /fi "imagename eq  DesktopHut Live v5.0.0.exe"`
would be:

```
Image Name
=========================
DesktopHut Live v5.0.0.ex
```

To overcome that limitation you can specify `csv` as the output format by the `/fo csv` switch

```
tasklist /fi "imagename eq  DesktopHut Live v5.0.0.exe" /fo csv | find /i "DesktopHut Live v5.0.0.exe" >nul
```

Since you are using `find` to set the `errorlevel`, there is no need to use a filter expression for `tasklist` so the entire command can be simplified to:

```
tasklist /fo csv | find /i "DesktopHut Live v5.0.0.exe" >nul
```

Comment: yeaaah you're right I saw that it was limited when I looked in the tasklist. Unfortunately I tried both replacing the line with the one you have told me and adding /fo csv and the program sent me the same error message:/

Comment: @David, If it is the exact same error message then you did it wrong. Either you didn't remove the extra quotes around `DesktopHut Live v5.0.0.exe` in the tasklist expression, or there is another instance of the `tasklist` with the wrong syntax in your code which you have not shown in your question. This is wrong: `tasklist /fi "imagename eq  "DesktopHut Live v5.0.0.exe" " /fo csv`. This is correct: `tasklist /fi "imagename eq  DesktopHut Live v5.0.0.exe" /fo csv`. Or remove the filter expression as I shown in the last line of answer.

Comment: thank you so much that was the problem and now it is working thanks to the /fo csv command thank you so much man